# Recovering a lost JR Pass or exchange voucher

Tags: japan, jr-passes

I will be travelling across Japan using JR Pass and have brought exchange voucher for it.
But given that a hard copy of JR pass needs to be carried along, there can be a chance that we may loose JR Pass. Is there any way to recover it?

Similarly in case of JR Pass exchange voucher, if we lose it before exchanging for JR Pass then is there a way to recover it?

Answer (score 1):

Neither JR Pass not voucher can be restored if lost. But if you lose voucher it may be refunded. Though in any way you will not be able to purchase new voucher or JR Pass in Japan.

https://m.jrpass.com/blog/what-to-do-if-you-have-forgotten-or-lost-your-japan-rail-pass

Comment: The JR Pass can now be purchased in Japan.

Comment: @fkraiem It depends on which JR pass you are referring to and it is usually more expensive.

Comment: @KH.Lee "The JR Pass" ("the" and capital P) in my book is an abbreviation for "the Japan Rail Pass". If I mean any rail pass issued by a JR company, I write "a JR pass" (lowercase p).